# Calling super class method in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    localizedTemplate : function (element) {
        template = _.template(element.html());

        return function (data) {
            return template($.extend({}, data, resource));
        };
    }
});

var DerivedView = BaseView.extend({
   initialize: function (options) {
       this.model = options.model;

       this.template = function () {
         return this.localizedTemplate($("#someTemplate"));
       };
   },

   render: function () {
       var output = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
       this.$el.append(output);
       return this;
   }
});
```

Why the above code is not working? why I am not able to call the someFunction in DerivedView? is there any way to achieve this?

I am using Backbone latest version.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
this.template = function () {
    return this.localizedTemplate($("#someTemplate"));
};
```

You're assigning a function to `this.template`. Note that `localizedTemplate` also returns a function:

```
return function (data) {
    return template($.extend({}, data, resource));
};
```

That means that `this.template` is a function which returns a function and that second function is the one that wants `this.model.toJSON()` as an argument.

You're doing this:

```
var output = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
```

The function in `this.template` ignores its arguments and returns a function, that leaves you with this function:

```
function () {
    return this.localizedTemplate($("#someTemplate"));
}
```

in `output`. You probably think `output` is a chunk of HTML at this point so you hand that to `append`:

```
this.$el.append(output);
```

But `output` is a function and what does [`append` do when called with a function](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-functionindex--html) as its argument? jQuery calls that function like this:

> **function(index, html)**
>   Type: Function()
>   A function that returns an HTML string, DOM element(s), or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old HTML value of the element as arguments. Within the function, `this` refers to the current element in the set.

So the `output` function will be called by jQuery's `append` and `append` will supply arguments that the compiled template function doesn't understand. The result is a big pile of confusion.

If you really want to do things like this then you'll want to call all the functions yourself so that you can get the right arguments to the right places:

```
var output = this.template()(this.model.toJSON());
// -----------------------^^
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YyJLR/

Or better, don't bother with all the extra wrappers at all. Say this in your view's `initialize`:

```
this.template = this.localizedTemplate($("#someTemplate"));
```

and then this in `render`:

```
var output = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BQjhS/

Also note that you don't need to `this.model = options.model`, the [view constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) will do that for you:

> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var DerivedView = BaseView.extend({
   someVariable: function(someData) {
      return this.someFunction(someData);
   }
});
```

Comment: Or simply `someVariable : this.someFunction(someData);` as I'm guessing `someVariable` is not supposed to be a method, but a value.

Comment: Yes, but I think in most scenarios you won't have `someData` until at least `view.initialize`.

Comment: Updated the code, but still it is not working. Please have a look at the new code and give your suggestion.

Comment: Within `localizedTemplate`, you need to prepend `this.` to your `template` variables. With what you have now, `template` is a global variable.

Comment: var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    localizedTemplate: function (element) {
        self = this;
        this.template = _.template(element.html());

        return function (data) {
            return self.template($.extend({}, data, resource));
        };
    }
});

Still not working... :(